# Large .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ipa

I extracted the ipa file to see what is inside and in the bundle .iOS file; I found another file .iOS file with type document; this file is 110 mb.

Does anyone know what is this file and how to reduce it or delete it from my project?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Ummm... you've covered up the name of the file - how can anybody know what it might be, or know whether or not you need it?

Comment: the file name is the app name - appName.iOS

Comment: can you open / view the png file to see what it is?

Comment: sorry the picture is misleading; not the highlights file. I mean the first file in the list. it is appName.iOS. So what is this file because it is a large file and I don't see it in other ipa files

Comment: Are you using Swift, and targeting older iOS versions? If so, it's very possibly the Swift run-time libraries needed to support the older version.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin; and I'm targeting iOS 10+

Comment: *"I'm using Xamarin"* ... You should have included that information in your question (and tags).

Comment: @AzabAF Hi , have a try with **Link Sdk Only** in build configuration to check whether can decrease the size of this file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#link-sdk-assemblies-only